# Conflict between pan and swipe gesture in the same view?

Tags: uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Is there anyway to distinguish pan and swipe gesture in the same view? I have 2 gestures work on a same view simultaneously by using the delegate

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

I did set the pan gesture's property minimumNumberOfTouches = 1. The problem is when I'm panning, the swipe gesture is triggered. How to make swipe gesture stop when I'm in panning process?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26805984/550393

Answer (score 8):

Try to call the *[requireGestureRecognizerToFail:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW36)* method in your swipe gesture

```
[swipeGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panGestureRecognizer];
```

This should cause the pan gesture to cancel the swipe gesture if the pan gesture is recognized or began.

Answer (score 0):

#### Next-decade solution!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let s = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bye))
    s.direction = .down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(s)
    
    let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
    p.require(toFail: s)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(p)
}
```

It's that simple now. Both will work.